# Using a binomial distribution table for rolling two dice

Tags: probability

There is this question that I'm stuck at since this morning. Usually combinations and permutations can be used to find binomial probability but our teacher told us to focus on using the binomial distribution probability TABLE. It is easy to use when there is a question of a coin tossed 4 times, what is the probability of getting exactly 2 heads. The probability of tossing a coin (heads of tails) is 0.5, and so I can just go to n=4, under 0.5 in the row of 2 under n=4 and I've got the probability. But what about rolling two dice? What is the probability of getting a total of 6? Rolling 1 die, the probability would be 1/6, but two dice would it be 1/36? How do i find the probability of getting a total of 6 from the binomial distribution table?

Comment: Out of $36$ equally probable outcomes, there are five ways to get that particular total: $$1+5 \quad=\quad 2+4 \quad=\quad 3+3 \quad=\quad 4+2 \quad=\quad 5+1.$$ I don't know how to get it from a table for the binomial distribution.

Comment: what if there is a question of "probability of getting a total strictly between 5 and 10"?

Comment: Again, I think there may be no quicker way than enumerating the outcomes.